# I need to compare the content in 2 strings

Tags: c++

I need to compare 2 (or more) string/char inputs and store them in a vector. 
For example, `"I love mondays"` and `"I love mondays"` should return true.

the problem is that for a string input, `strcmp()` does not work because it needs char. 
But if the input is the type char array it does not register the spaces and only stores the `"I"`.

so I tried with `cin.getline()` but it did not work properly in a loop.
so I used `cin.ignore()` in the loop and everything works fine!
...except now the inputs ignores the first character (result: `" love mondays"`).

Comment: I think it's time to invest in [a couple of good books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list/388282#388282). They should teach you how to compare [`std::string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) objects. They should hopefully also teach you how to [read whole lines](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) from any input stream.

Comment: Please provide your code

Comment: `getline` will work in a loop, compare will simply work with the `==` operator for strings. Please provide your code to let us see what you did wrong.

Comment: Your main problem is that you're using `>>` to read user input elsewhere. Don't do that.

Comment: It seems you have a question about std::cin. Perhaps you can change the title to reflect that. std::string comparison works by using str1 == st2; strcmp expects const char* arguments which a char array converts to.

Answer (score 2):

You can read from input with getline(cin, string); read more: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/

You can simply compare two strings with == which returns true if the strings are equal and false otherwise.

Edit:

Here is a code with education purpose:

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    //try to always use string w/ C++
    std::string myStr1, myStr2;
    //read first string
    std::cout << "Input first string: ";
    std::getline(std::cin, myStr1);
    //read second string
    std::cout << "Input second string: ";
    std::getline(std::cin, myStr2);

    //compare strings, this is case sensitive
    if(myStr1 == myStr2 )
     std::cout << "The string are the same";
    else
     std::cout << "The string are not the same";

    return 0;
}

It's that easy, have fun learning.

Answer (score 0):

Try to always use strings instead of char arrays.

You can use .compare() in that case - http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/compare/

You can also use .c_str() to compare them using strcmp - http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/c_str/

Comment: It might be worth to mention that `std::string` overloads operator `==` and `!=` in a senseful way (in opposition to them used for `char*` et al.)

Comment: _You can also use .c_str()_ You can but you shouldn't (IMHO). ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I thing you can use strings and strcmp with the string method c_str() that  return a char array.

Comment: What does this add to the answer of [Xellos](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58111776/7478597)?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you like to start with this example:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::string a;
    std::string b;

    for(;;)
    {
        std::getline(std::cin, a);
        std::getline(std::cin, b);

        // terminate the loop if no more input comes in or
        // something goes wrong. To stop input, use CTRL-D on linux like shell
        if ( std::cin.eof() || std::cin.fail() ) break;

        std::cout << "First string: " << a << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Second string: " << b << std::endl;

        // Compare strings is quite simple in C++, use operator==
        if ( a == b )
        {
            std::cout << "Strings are equal" << std::endl;
        } else {
            std::cout << "Strings are NOT equal" << std::endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Further readings for operators provides from `std::string`: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_cmp

Answer (score 0):

You can read a line of text at a time by using

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
…
string readString;
getline(cin, readString);
```

You can find more about `getline` at [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/) and [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline).

You can simply compare two strings using the [comparison operators declared for `std::string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_cmp).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {

  string myStr1, myStr2;
  // read first string
  cout << "Input first string: ";
  getline(cin, myStr1);

  // read second string
  cout << "Input second string: ";
  getline(cin, myStr2);

  // compare strings, this is case sensitive
  if (myStr1 == myStr2){
    cout << "The string are the same" << endl;
  }
  else {
    cout << "The string are not the same" << endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```